# MySQL query with assignment operators and variables works with MySQL 5.7 but not in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a query, that works with rows having 4 hierachies in one table. Now i query the table with the ID of the lowest level and get as result 4 rows of the parents and the child.

Here is a sample from the DB:

| id | title | parent | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Bavaria | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Swabia | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | Augsburg | 3 | 4 |

This works all the time in mysql 5.7 like this:

```
SELECT id, type, title FROM ( SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent FROM category WHERE id = _id) AS parent, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl 
FROM (SELECT @r := 4, @l := 0) vars, category h WHERE @r <> 0) T1 
JOIN category T2 ON T1._id = T2.id 
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

Result in MySql 5.7:

| id | type | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Germany |
| 2 | 2 | Bavaria |
| 3 | 3 | Swabia |
| 4 | 4 | Augsburg |

Under Mysql 8 i don't get an error but just no result.

**Additional Info**
According to the documentation, under both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL8.0, incrementing a variable itself is not guaranteed.

> SET @a = @a + 1"; With other statements, such as SELECT, you might get
> the expected results, but it's not guaranteed. With the following
> statement, you might think that MySQL first evaluates @a and then
> makes an assignment ...

I suspect that this is why the query does not work: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

**Additional Info 2 (Explanation)**

> Beginning with MySQL 8.0.22, a reference to a user variable in a
> prepared statement has its type determined when the statement is first
> prepared, and retains this type each time the statement is executed
> thereafter. Similarly, the type of a user variable employed in a
> statement within a stored procedure is determined the first time the
> stored procedure is invoked, and retains this type with each
> subsequent invocation.

---

Possibly this would be an alternative in MySql 8 but i need a query that works in both:

```
with recursive parent_cats (id, parent, title, type) AS (
  SELECT id, parent, title, type
  FROM category
  WHERE id = 4
  union all
  SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.title, t.type
  FROM category t INNER JOIN parent_cats pc
  ON t.id = pc.parent
)
SELECT * FROM parent_cats;
```

Comment: The processing order is not definite. When you use user-defined variables then only one-level one-table query w/o aggregating may produce determnistic output. Your query have 3 nesting levels - of course the output is not predictable. In your particular case - I think that `@r AS _id` in the subquery is assumed as NULL which produces empty output.

Comment: Explain the task itself - it seems that in MySQL 8 your query may be simplified and does not need in UDV usage at all.

Comment: Thanks, I will explain the task, but i need a query that works in 5.7 AND 8

Comment: You may not get that (a query that works in both); 8 supports doing this correctly, with a recursive cte, and deprecates setting variables in a select (though they did not intentionally break that yet).  Note that 5.7 reaches end of life in a few months and will no longer receive security updates; at that point it should be treated as insecure.

Comment: I know but there are global os projects still running on 5.7 and we cannot change that in our product.

Comment: Why do you say it returns no result on MySQL 8.0? It does return a result: https://dbfiddle.uk/Gc-UEYcx

Comment: @BillKarwin The same query return no results when running under 8.0 on our server. Don't know why at the moment.

Comment: I added some extra info that might explain why the query sometimes fail under mysql 8.